# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.setAwait(boolean)

Tags: java, jsp

Why do I get this error when I try to run Tomcat server v7.0.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.setAwait(boolean)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.setAwait(Bootstrap.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException` indicates incompatible jar files

Answer (score 0):

I just googled, even if my research come from former Tomcat version it can give you a clue....

It could be linked to the catalina.jar file in the lib/ext
If you have a former version of that file try to restore it.

It could also come from the j2ee.jar in your server\lib.
Archive it somewhere else and launch again.

Good luck

[j2ee.jar](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22142926/Tomcat-5-5-startup-problems-getting-java-lang-NoSuchMethodException-org-apache-catalina-startup-Catalina-setAwait-boolean.html)
[catalina.jar](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/0446kc6cqs/5-0-19-wont-start-on-anything-other-thatn-nix)